# ePSXe: Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2 Freezes

Tags: epsxe, tony-hawks-pro-skater-2

I've just downloaded ePSXe and I'm having a hard time trying to play Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2. The intro animation shows correctly and so does the menu, but when I try to play anything, either a Career Mode, a Single Session or a Free Skate, it freezes, bringing me a black screen where nothing shows up and nothing happens. The music continues to play though.

I've tried with both CD and ISO. I've also played with the configurations a few times and it didn't help.

I didn't have the opportunity to try another game yet, but I'd like to know what might be going on. Is it possible that the problem is being caused by the ISO itself?

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a US copy of the game on a EU bios file you may be experiencing region-locking issues.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have found an alternative solution. I'm using another emulator, PSXeven, and it runs the game perfectly, with CD or ISO.

I'd like to know why I'm not able to play this game using ePSXe though, since I've checked some compatibilities lists and it should work fine.

Comment: Are you using the same bios file on both emulators?

Comment: check the video plugin